# Trying to put inline elts with jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/WEuzB/

I'm tryign to make the comment and the author appear on the same line, with the author+delete button right floated

But it's complicated with jquery-mobile, any help or advise on that would be appreciated

thx

**Updated** here: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/WEuzB/8/ almost good

Comment: This does what you need maybe http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WEuzB/2/

Comment: @Joy almost I would like the left and right words vertically aligned

Comment: You can do that using `height` and `line-height` set to same value. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WEuzB/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/5/

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:40px;">how you?</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; float:right;">
        <b>Sarah Pink</b>
        <a href="" type="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** - to shrink the height - http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/10/

CSS

```
.ui-li-static.ui-li { padding: 0 15px !important } /* need to redefine a jquery set style */
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:40px;">how you?</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; float:right;">
        <b style="display:inline-block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:40px;">Sarah Pink</b>
        <a href="" type="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx to you and Joy, yours simpler, is it possible to shrink more in height, forcing line-height:25px; doesnt seems to have any effect

Comment: Updated the answer with the shrank height

Comment: good job it's nice on both chrome and firefox, did not look IE, thx

Comment: @Toth if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887491/jquerymobile-listview-custom-css