# jquerymobile listview custom css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/11/

On this example I'm tring to display the comment message anchored on left, and the commenter on right,

but I would like to larger message (or smaller screen) that it does not overlap like shown in example,

I'm looking for a wrap text + float right property

of course a margin-right: 250px, would not be good on Comments' div (for small screen there would be nothing

thx

**Edit**; Also if you can explain why this solution http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/12/ doesn't work (text is hidden for some reason)

**Edit 2** : almost working http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/13, or http://jsfiddle.net/WEuzB/31/ , but I would like the commenter on bottom right corner, and a better comment text wrapping than width 60% would be cool if possible

edit3: finally doing it with *li data-role="list-divider"* for author name, and *li* for message, simpler better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing it with li data-role="list-divider" separating messages + showing author name

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xhellzx/WEuzB/26/

Like this?

I just moved it using "position:relative" and manipulating the top and right edge values.

Comment: @ca11111 Yes, definitely much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/8ceuD/5/